# Joda time conversion incorrect with non-DST timezone

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

I'm experiencing and issue with Joda that I believe may be a bug.  However it is quite possible I'm making a mistake using the library, so please give me your feedback.

We've been using joda in production to convert times between our database storage format (UTC), and the user's timezone preference.  The employees using the system all work from Arizona, which does not observe daylight savings time.  Among other things, this system tracks start times for sporting events across the country.

Joda was working great for us, until we noticed that the day before the timechange we were getting some incorrect results.  We found that joda seemed to be changing to daylight savings time at midnight UTC, instead of at the appropriate time for the specific timezone.  Furthermore this problem only occurs when converting times between a DST-observing state to a non-DST state such as Arizona.

I've produced a full test case that illustrates this problem.  As you will see, joda provides the expected result for all US/Eastern -> US/Pacific test cases.  For US/Arizona -> US/Pacific, it works throughout the year before the november change and afterwards.  However on the day of the time change (nov 6th) the time is incorrect.   There may also be an issue around the march time change, though I have not tested it exhaustively yet.

Here is the output from the provided test (**the entry for November 6th illustrates the error**):

```
=== November 1st, Expected Result (0 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-11-01 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-01 09:00. Change (0 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-11-01 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-01 09:00. Change (0 hour).

=======================================

=== November 6th, Expected Result (0 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-11-06 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-06 09:00. Change (0 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-11-06 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-06 08:00. Change (-1 hour).

=======================================

=== November 12th, Expected Result (-1 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-11-12 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-12 08:00. Change (-1 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-11-12 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-12 08:00. Change (-1 hour).

=======================================

=== March 12th, Expected Result (-1 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-03-12 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-12 08:00. Change (-1 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-03-12 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-12 08:00. Change (-1 hour).

=======================================

=== March 14th, Expected Result (0 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-03-14 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-14 09:00. Change (0 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-03-14 09:00 from US/Arizona to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-14 09:00. Change (0 hour).

=======================================

=== November 1st, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-11-01 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-01 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-11-01 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-01 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

=======================================

=== November 6th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-11-06 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-06 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-11-06 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-06 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

=======================================

=== November 12th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-11-12 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-12 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-11-12 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-11-12 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

=======================================

=== March 12th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-03-12 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-12 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-03-12 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-12 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

=======================================

=== March 14th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===
java:
Converting 2010-03-14 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-14 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

joda:
Converting 2010-03-14 09:00 from US/Eastern to US/Pacific.
Result: 2010-03-14 06:00. Change (-3 hour).

=======================================
```

And here is the full test case:

```
package com.test.time;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeTest {
    Calendar nov6;
    Calendar nov1;
    Calendar nov12;

    Calendar mar12;
    Calendar mar14;

    @Before
    public void doBefore() {
        // November 1st 2010, 9:00pm (DST is active)
        nov1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        nov1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
        nov1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        nov1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nov1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        nov1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
        nov1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10); // November
        nov1.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        // November 6st 2010, 9:00pm (DST is still active until early AM
        // november 7th)
        nov6 = Calendar.getInstance();
        nov6.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
        nov6.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        nov6.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nov6.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        nov6.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
        nov6.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10); // November
        nov6.set(Calendar.DATE, 6);

        // November 12th 2010, 9:00pm (DST has ended)
        nov12 = Calendar.getInstance();
        nov12.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
        nov12.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        nov12.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nov12.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        nov12.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
        nov12.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10); // November
        nov12.set(Calendar.DATE, 12);

        // March 12th 2011, 9:00pm (DST has ended, will begin early a.m. march
        // 13th)
        mar12 = Calendar.getInstance();
        mar12.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
        mar12.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        mar12.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        mar12.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        mar12.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
        mar12.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2); // March
        mar12.set(Calendar.DATE, 12);

        // March 14th 2011, 9:00pm (DST has started)
        mar14 = Calendar.getInstance();
        mar14.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
        mar14.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        mar14.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        mar14.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        mar14.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
        mar14.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2); // March
        mar14.set(Calendar.DATE, 14);
    }

    @Test
    public void testArizonaToPacific() {
        System.out.println("=== November 1st, Expected Result (0 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(nov1.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(nov1.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== November 6th, Expected Result (0 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(nov6.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(nov6.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== November 12th, Expected Result (-1 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(nov12.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(nov12.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== March 12th, Expected Result (-1 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(mar12.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(mar12.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== March 14th, Expected Result (0 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(mar14.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(mar14.getTime(), "US/Arizona", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");
    }

    @Test
    public void testEasternToPacific() {
        System.out.println("=== November 1st, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(nov1.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(nov1.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== November 6th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(nov6.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(nov6.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== November 12th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(nov12.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(nov12.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== March 12th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(mar12.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(mar12.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");

        System.out.println("=== March 14th, Expected Result (-3 hour) ===");
        timeTestJava(mar14.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        timeTestJoda(mar14.getTime(), "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific");
        System.out.println("=======================================\n");
    }

    // print some output from the test
    private void print(Date startTime, String text, String from, String to,
            Date output) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");

        System.out.println(text + ":");
        System.out.println("Converting " + sdf.format(startTime) + " from "
                + from + " to " + to + ".");
        long difference = output.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
        System.out.println("Result: " + sdf.format(output) + ". Change ("
                + difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 + " hour).\n");
    }

    // wrapper around joda test
    private void timeTestJoda(Date startTime, String from, String to) {
        Date output = convertJodaOld(startTime, TimeZone.getTimeZone(from),
                TimeZone.getTimeZone(to));
        print(startTime, "joda", from, to, output);
    }

    // wrapper around java test
    private void timeTestJava(Date startTime, String from, String to) {
        Date output = convertJava(startTime, TimeZone.getTimeZone(from),
                TimeZone.getTimeZone(to));
        print(startTime, "java", from, to, output);
    }

    // Joda implementation, works before and after DST change, but not during
    // the period from 2am-7am UTC on the day of the change
    public Date convertJodaOld(Date dt, TimeZone from, TimeZone to) {
        DateTimeZone tzFrom = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(from);
        DateTimeZone tzTo = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(to);

        Date utc = new Date(tzFrom.convertLocalToUTC(dt.getTime(), false));
        Date convertedTime = new Date(tzTo.convertUTCToLocal(utc.getTime()));
        return convertedTime;
    }

    // Java implementation. Works.
    public Date convertJava(Date dt, TimeZone from, TimeZone to) {
        long fromOffset = from.getOffset(dt.getTime());
        long toOffset = to.getOffset(dt.getTime());

        long convertedTime = dt.getTime() - (fromOffset - toOffset);
        return new Date(convertedTime);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT use 'US/Arizona', it's obsolete.

Use 'America/Phoenix'

Same goes for 'US/Pacific', use 'America/Los_Angeles' instead.

Comment: Nice to know, however using the timezones you suggest does not affect the test results. Do you have a link to information on the US/* timezones being obsolete?

Comment: @samspot. Here is the 'official' list -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones.  This is somewhat unofficial info -> http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?s=default&tz=US/Pacific

Comment: @samspot. Looks to me that you are actually not using Joda time.  Construct DateTime objects and see that you still have problem.  I've been using DateTime throughout my code and tested heavily around standard/daylight changes because they are critical for our system.  Joda time classes always returned correct results.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  After digging in further with DateTime, i found that joda is representing my time correctly internally, but when i try to convert back to a java Date (with DateTime.toDate()), issues arise.  The whole ui is tightly coupled to java.util.Date objects, so we really need a way to convert to them in a way that will display appropriately.